# CRC usage when ack disabled in nRF24L01

Tags: arduino-uno, library, nrf24l01+, wireless

In the documentation of the nRF24L01 library I use ([library](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html)), the CRC state (on/off) and length can be set or get. It seems to be used for auto ack, but when I switch auto ack off, what is the use of CRC? Can I somehow read the CRC value or use it somehow in a useful way?

The reason is, I get sometimes wrong values and would like the CRC for that, but otherwise I need to implement my own CRC byte(s) in the payload.

(also, when I put my finger against the PCB side on the side where the PCB antenna is placed, but not touching the antenna, I get many more messages).

Comment: The chip itself deals with CRC calculation and discards any that fail the check, you don't get to see the CRC. You get faulty packets when connection between Arduino and the nRF is finicky or when power to the module isn't the most table, use better wires (definitely not a ribbon cable) and decoupling capacitors. See the datasheet for more details about special cases of using CRC (Enchanced Shockburst and so on).

Comment: @Avamandar ... I use an adapter which afaik already contains the capacitors (also there wouldn't be a possibility to add these manual close to VCC/GND anyway). I use 5V (and the adapter converts it into 3.3V). 
I would have to check the special cases regarding enhanced shockburst (I don't want to use the ack-mechanism).

Comment: You don't have to use auto-ack to keep CRC enabled, if my memory serves me correctly.

Comment: @Avamandar True, it seems different options, but since there is no way to use CRC directly, the only possibility it's used internally in the chip. However, I assume it does not start resending by itself in case of an incorrect CRC and I cannot know the CRC value, so a CRC without an ack does not seem very useful.

Comment: @Avamandar ... the default way afaik is to use dupont cables, I assume you don't consider those ribbon cables?

Comment: Dupont cables should work fine. Resending, auto-ack and CRC are all separate features that work almost individually. The library has functions for changing that too.

Comment: I use dupont and seems to work fine so far indeed, I never used flat cable. I guess I need to do some testing to see how much the CRC influences correct transfers.

Comment: `(also, when I put my finger against the PCB side on the side where the PCB antenna is placed, but not touching the antenna, I get many more messages).` - You may have your gain set too high or your modules too close together and the signal is distorting through too much power (saturating the receiver). Your finger is attenuating the signal. Or the other way around and there's not enough signal and your finger is acting as a crude ground plane for the dipole.

Comment: @Majenko that might be the case (too close together, like 5-15 cm and MAX PA level). I will try to decrease it.... however, what if I don't know the distance while in use? In a real situation some slaves might be close, others might be further away... I cannot select it per slave device/port.

Comment: If they are just slaves to a single master then it's the distance from the slaves to the master that you need to worry about, not the distance between slaves. Anything further than about 1m you don't really need to worry I think. Experiment. See what PA level gives the best results over the distance range you are expecting. Maybe give a "LOW" and "HIGH" power switch on the unit.

Comment: @Majenko ... yes that is what I meant (I mean some slaves will be close to the master, some might be close to the master). So I guess it's best to have at least some distance between all slaves to the master ... or maybe in case two are close together, I might go for a wired solution for one of them.